# Most secure way to print on local printer while in remote sessioin

Tags: printer

First of all a hello to everyone.
I am trying to work a solution for my client.

1. The client wants to access a machine at SITE-B remotely.
2. The client wants to access the files at SITE-B using a software installed
   at the remote machine.
3. Most important ::: 
   While the client is working on a software on the remote machine at SITE-B, he wants to print at the local printer at SITE-A while in remote session.

I have considered RDP but I am just concerned with the security.
All systems are WINDOWS 7 PRO.

The other option is using VPN but I have not been able to print locally.

TeamViewer etc... are not being considered because of security risks and also the
cost involved for licences.

Please throw some light on this issue and help me to design the solution.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What's your threat model? What do you fear an attacker might do?

Comment: I was thinking to have a VPN like security on the network. Though the data is not that secretive but its the privacy factor, I will say.

Answer (score 0):

A bridged ethernet VPN is the answer. This will connect Site A and Site B together in both directions allowing:

```
RDP from A to B
Printing from B to A
```

A "regular" (no ethernet bridge) VPN setup wont allow the remote PC at Site B to see the printer at A.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Can you share some resources on HOW TO SETUP or other pointers. I am quite new to this whole concept and would love to learn more. Thank you once again.